# Groovy script: How to define a range with two different variables

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm new to groovy scripting in Jenkins Active choice reactive paramters and I got stuck with the below problem.

Say there are two variables

int value1=30

int value2=36

Here, I should create a list range from value1 to value2

which means list r should be [30,31,32,33,34,35,36].

I tried like below but didn't worked..!!

```
int value = 1000
int value2 = 1003

def r = ${value}..${value2}

println "Values: ${r}"
```

Please help how this can be achieved.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost. Just enclose the range in parens and don't use String interpolation syntax:

```
def r = (value1..value2)

assert r == [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
```

The equality works because `r` is an [`IntRange`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/lang/IntRange.html) instance, which implements the `List` interface.